# PureFTPd is using ports above 50000 even with PassivePortRange specified

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, firewall

I have installed the pure-ftpd package with PureFTP 1.0.24 on Ubuntu 10.04 using apt-get.

Even though, this is the default port range, I've added the file /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange containing:

```
30000 50000
```

This does add the correct option to the command as it is run (`-p 30000:50000`), but for some reason, I still get connections trying to use ports above 50000.  I think the problem is that these are active ftp sessions, but what's the point of specifying a port range if it only works for passive mode?  Then I still need to open all the ports in my firewall...

Is there a way to specify a port range for all connections (rather than just passive ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [W]hat's the point of specifying a port range if it only works for passive mode? Then I still need to open all the ports in my firewall...

From the server's point of view, active connections are outgoing connections, so that premise is wrong.

Since the *client* has to accept the incoming active connection, the client also specifies which port is going to be used. This is part of the FTP specification. Limiting the port range server-side doesn't make any sense in this case. What if the client can only accept incoming connections between ports 20000 and 25000?

Comment: Ahh!! Thank you.  The problem was that I happened to be connecting from another server with similar port-range restrictions, so I was getting error messages like "Could not open data connection to port 59111: Connection timed out" - and thinking this was referring to the server port, but it was actually referring to the client port.  So the answer for my situation (connecting from a client with a limited port-range open), is to use passive ftp! :)